# Unrestricted file write in Java

Tags: java, file-upload, file-system

Would it be possible to write a file to a directory outside of the uploads folder if the $ext variable is used controlled and unrestricted? The uploads directory is empty except for the freshly created file.

```
val file = new File("uploads/image.$ext")
Files.write(file.toPath, bytes)
```

Comment: Is this Java on Desktop?  Generally, Java for desktop has no sandboxing unless you explicitly opt-in

Comment: It is run on a web server. I added more information to multithr3at3d answer.

Comment: It would find it bad enough that files could be written over, and that it is hard to tell if the file transmission is complete or not. And obviously this is Kotlin running in the JVM, not Java.

Comment: This is Java, not Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about your uploads directory. Unless there is other code you are not showing that performs additional checks and validations, directory traversal is probably trivial.

Comment: The problem isn't the uploads directory itself. The problem is that i can't keep writing on the path to change directory. For instance, if i change the $ext to ./../test.txt the path will be uploads/image../../test.txt which is not a correct path. I suspect the issue is that uploads is a directory, but there is no directory in uploads called "image.." which is why I get FileNotFound error.